# Please explain how to install old version of arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: arm-none-eabi-gcc

I want to compile specific embedded project, and with newest version of arm cross compiler installed from repository it doesn't work. So author is recommend to use previous version (10.3.1) instead current.
Try to find older version in repository and cannot find

Please explain step by step how to do this

The project itself and description is here:
https://github.com/fagci/uv-k5-firmware-fagci-mod

Old version of arm-none-eabi-gcc is here:
https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-rm

I try to install it from source, but unfortunately he make some errors
I need some easiest way to do this, better if it will be installation from repository precompiled version 10.3.1
How to do this i don't know

Comment: Download "gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2 ", extract this somewhere, use the compiler in the "bin" folder and make sure your paths are set correctly.  You might have to make an environment file and source it, i.e. set all of your paths, variables, etc so the right libraries and things are picked up.

Comment: I try to do this but i dont know how to setup correct PATH, and what PATH is must be, about variables and library's same. How can i know where it must be? I need simple way like add another repository and automatically install from it